# How to use QComboBox as delegate with QTableView

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qtableview, qcombobox

The code below creates a single `QTableView`. Double-clicking its item will set it with a delegated `QComboBox`.

**Problem**:
When the `ComboBox` is clicked its pull-down menu shows up momentary and then it collapses back to its unrolled state.

[image]

If the `comboBox` would be set to be editable using `combox.setEditable(True)`, 
the pull-down menu would stay open as desired. But then the `combobox`'s items become editable. And it is not what needed. Since the `combobox`'s items should only be selectable.

How to fix the self-collapsing `combobox`'s behavior?

P.s. I have noticed then when `ComboBox` is set to be editable and its pull-down menu is unrolled the model's `data()` is constantly being called... is self-collapsing behavior could probably triggered by model?

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class ComboDelegate(QItemDelegate):
    comboItems=['Combo_Zero', 'Combo_One','Combo_Two']
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, proxyModelIndex):
        combo = QComboBox(parent)
        combo.addItems(self.comboItems)
        # combo.setEditable(True)
        self.connect(combo, SIGNAL("currentIndexChanged(int)"), self, SLOT("currentIndexChanged()"))
        return combo

    def setModelData(self, combo, model, index):
        comboIndex=combo.currentIndex()
        text=self.comboItems[comboIndex]        
        model.setData(index, text)
        print '\t\t\t ...setModelData() 1', text

    @pyqtSlot()
    def currentIndexChanged(self): 
        self.commitData.emit(self.sender())

class MyModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, *args):
        QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent, *args)
        self.items=['Data_Item01','Data_Item02','Data_Item03']

    def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.items)
    def columnCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return 1

    def data(self, index, role):        
        if not index.isValid(): return QVariant()

        row=index.row()
        item=self.items[row]

        if row>len(self.items): return QVariant()

        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            print ' << >> MyModel.data() returning ...', item
            return QVariant(item) 

    def flags(self, index):
        return Qt.ItemIsEditable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled

    def setData(self, index, text):
        self.items[index.row()]=text

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    model = MyModel()
    tableView = QTableView()
    tableView.setModel(model)

    delegate = ComboDelegate()

    tableView.setItemDelegate(delegate)
    tableView.resizeRowsToContents()

    tableView.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your original code is working in PyQt5, the `combobox` stays open. But the user has to click to open the editor and then to click to open the `combobox`. To avoid this i replaced `QComboBox` by `QlistWidget` in your code. Additionally i set `editorGeometry`:

```
import sys
# from PyQt4.QtCore import *
# from PyQt4.QtGui import *

from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class ComboDelegate(QItemDelegate):
    editorItems=['Combo_Zero', 'Combo_One','Combo_Two']
    height = 25
    width = 200
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = QListWidget(parent)
        # editor.addItems(self.editorItems)
        # editor.setEditable(True)
        editor.currentItemChanged.connect(self.currentItemChanged)
        return editor

    def setEditorData(self,editor,index):
        z = 0
        for item in self.editorItems:
            ai = QListWidgetItem(item)
            editor.addItem(ai)
            if item == index.data():
                editor.setCurrentItem(editor.item(z))
            z += 1
        editor.setGeometry(0,index.row()*self.height,self.width,self.height*len(self.editorItems))

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        editorIndex=editor.currentIndex()
        text=editor.currentItem().text() 
        model.setData(index, text)
        # print '\t\t\t ...setModelData() 1', text

    @pyqtSlot()
    def currentItemChanged(self): 
        self.commitData.emit(self.sender())

class MyModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, *args):
        QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent, *args)
        self.items=['Data_Item01','Data_Item02','Data_Item03']

    def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.items)
    def columnCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return 1

    def data(self, index, role):        
        if not index.isValid(): return QVariant()

        row=index.row()
        item=self.items[row]

        if row>len(self.items): return QVariant()

        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            # print ' << >> MyModel.data() returning ...', item
            return QVariant(item) 

    def flags(self, index):
        return Qt.ItemIsEditable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled

    def setData(self, index, text):
        self.items[index.row()]=text

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    model = MyModel()
    tableView = QTableView()
    tableView.setModel(model)

    delegate = ComboDelegate()

    tableView.setItemDelegate(delegate)
    for i in range(0,tableView.model().rowCount()):
        tableView.setRowHeight(i,tableView.itemDelegate().height)
    for i in range(0,tableView.model().columnCount()):
        tableView.setColumnWidth(i,tableView.itemDelegate().width)

    tableView.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the attempt to substitute a `QComboBox` with `QToolButton` linked to `QMenu` and `QAction`s.

The look and feel is about the same as `QComboBox` with an additional feature of having an ability to set multiple `QActions` checked (currently it is not possible to have multiple combo box's items checked).

[image]

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class ComboDelegate(QItemDelegate):
    comboItems=['Combo_Zero', 'Combo_One','Combo_Two']
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QItemDelegate.__init__(self, parent=None)
        self.actionEmitted=None

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        if not index.isValid(): return

        model=index.model()
        itemName=model.data(index, Qt.DisplayRole)

        toolButton=QToolButton(parent)
        toolButton.setText( itemName.toString() )

        toolButton.setPopupMode(QToolButton.InstantPopup)        

        menu=QMenu(parent)

        action1=QAction('Action 01', menu, checkable=True)
        action2=QAction('Action 02', menu, checkable=True)
        action3=QAction('Action 03', menu, checkable=True)

        action1.setObjectName('Action 01')
        action2.setObjectName('Action 02')
        action3.setObjectName('Action 03')       

        action1.setChecked(True)
        action3.setChecked(True)

        self.connect(action1, SIGNAL("triggered(bool)"), self, SLOT("actionTriggered()"))
        self.connect(action2, SIGNAL("triggered(bool)"), self, SLOT("actionTriggered()"))
        self.connect(action3, SIGNAL("triggered(bool)"), self, SLOT("actionTriggered()"))

        menu.addAction(action1)
        menu.addAction(action2)
        menu.addAction(action3)

        toolButton.setMenu(menu) 

        return toolButton

    def setModelData(self, toolButton, model, index):
        print '\t\t\t ...setModelData() 1', toolButton, model, index

        if not self.actionEmitted: return

        menu=toolButton.menu()
        for action in menu.actions():
            actionName=action.objectName()
            actionStatus=action.isChecked()            
            if actionStatus:
                model.setData(index, actionName)
                print '####', actionName, actionStatus

    @pyqtSlot()
    def actionTriggered(self): 
        self.actionEmitted=self.sender()        
        self.commitData.emit( self.actionEmitted )
        print 'actionTriggered.....', self.actionEmitted


class MyModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, *args):
        QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent, *args)
        self.items=['Data_Item01','Data_Item02','Data_Item03']

    def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.items)
    def columnCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return 1

    def data(self, index, role):        
        if not index.isValid(): return QVariant()

        row=index.row()
        item=self.items[row]

        if row>len(self.items): return QVariant()

        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            print ' << >> MyModel.data() returning ...', item
            return QVariant(item) 

    def flags(self, index):
        return Qt.ItemIsEditable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled

    def setData(self, index, itemName):
        self.items[index.row()]=itemName

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    combo=QComboBox()
    combo.addItems(['Combo_Zero', 'Combo_One','Combo_Two'])

    model = MyModel()
    tableView = QTableView()
    tableView.setModel(model)

    delegate = ComboDelegate(tableView)

    tableView.setItemDelegate(delegate)
    tableView.resizeRowsToContents()

    tableView.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```